# Automatizar inserção de registros no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Olá, eu estou desenvolvendo um sistemo no qual preciso de uma lista com todos os times de futebol do mundo e seus respectivos campeonatos. Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura no meu banco de dados:

**tb_time**(id, nome, tb_campeonato_id) 



 
**tb_campeonado**(id, filiacao, pais, nome)

Eu achei no site [resultados.com](http://resultados.com) uma ótima base de times mas eu não sei bem como poderia extrair tais informações do site. Eu pensei em criar um script php onde eu pudesse estabelecer o nome do campeonato e do país e em seguida cadastrar todos os times de uma lista que pertencesse ao devido campeonato mas mesmo assim demandaria muito esforço manual. O que eu gostaria de saber é se alguém pode me sugerir uma forma mais automatizada de fazer isso pois como eu pensei daria um baita trabalho de fazer em cada campeonato e em cada país do mundo. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Se eu não estou enganado, tem uma maneira de pegar um banco de dados e exportar para um txt a fim de utilizá-lo em outros projetos.

Comment: Acho que a parte mais complicada é pegar as informações do site.

Comment: Alguém me dá uma ajuda, por favor!